# Icon size using media queries

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I am developing an app which runns on mobile and desktop browsers. I'm trying to find a sollution that could fix my icon size. I want icons to be small on desktop browsers but bigger on mobile browsers.

Can media queries detect screen density and if so can screen desinity determine my icon size?

And another thing: Is it better to detect screen size or density and adjust icons depending on the better choice.

Comment: If your icons are images, this is a topic that's been lighting up web development blogs for months. It's complicated to do. If you're using an icon font, then it's easy.

Comment: I am using .PNG images

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a media query that detects pixel density. Here is an example:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Then you would change your background image and background image size here */
}
```

There is also a ton more info in [this article at CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

Comment: Note this type of query will only work on webkit browsers, so it will not work Opera mini, IE on windows phone, or firefox mobile, desktop firefox, or desktop IE or desktop Opera (yet, Opera is moving to webkit soon)

Comment: @ryan there are prefixed variants for Opera and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

The question of whether to target device size or pixel density is tricky: it will depend on the specifics each time, and there's nothing to say you shouldn't combine both in your site. The media query you want to cover everything is:

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

   /* your retina rules here */

}
```

...which is probably the most helpful if you're sticking with PNGs rather than SVG graphics or an icon font. I recommend looking at [retinafy.me](http://retinafy.me/) - it's a useful resource (but not free), which is where that code came from.